# How to enter Jinja variables as HTML values

Tags: html, web, jinja2

I am using Jinja and am trying to set the "value" of the option to a variable. I tried this: `<option value = {{stock['name']}}>{{stock['name]}}</option>`, but it thinks that the `{{stock['name'is a string`, and the bits after that are normal. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The stock['name'] may be int or string but still the value will be put as a string like you said it thinks so. So, after you select your option and pass back to server via form or ajax or whatever then in the server side you can typecast the value back to integer and use it like:

```
@app.route('/stocks',methods=['GET','POST'])
def func():
   if request.form.get('stock'):
       stock_value = int(request.form.get('stock'))
   # like so you can use the integer value if you want
```

but if I did not get you , can you make it clear again?

Comment: No, sorry, I already got the answer. It was simply because I, for some reason, needed to put spaces between the {{ and the content inside. Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 0):

I simply needed to add spaces, so that the code is `{{ stock['name'] }}`